# How can i use the forloop counter in django without resetting

Tags: python, django

I have this code

```
{% for d in list1 %}
    {% for o in d.list2 %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter}} </td>
            <td>{{ o.name}}</td>
          </tr>
    {% endfor  %}
{% endfor %}
```

The counter is resetting after the parent loop changes.

Is there any way to make the counter not reset for each list1 loop. I want to list all items in list2 fro all `d` in list1 starting for `0 - 10`

Comment: You will have to create flat list in the view and pass it to template rather than nested list.

Comment: didn't try yet, but probably you could see `with`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Comment: in the outer loop, `{% with counter=forloop.counter %}` while in the inner loop, `{{ counter }}`

Comment: oh sorry the `with` won't meet your needs. ;(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`forloop.counter`, as you have discovered, only refers to the counter of the inner loop. You can access the counter of the outer loop using `forloop.parentloop.counter`, which will help a little bit.

However, if you have data like so:

```
list1 = [
    {'list2': [
        {'name': 'd1 o1'},
        {'name': 'd1 o2'}]},
    {'list2': [
        {'name': 'd2 o1'},
        {'name': 'd2 o2'},
        {'name': 'd2 o3'}]},
    {'list2': [
        {'name': 'd3 o1'},
        {'name': 'd3 o2'}]}
]
```

and you are wanting to produce output like:

```
<tr><td>1 </td><td> d1 o1 </td></tr>
<tr><td>2 </td><td> d1 o2 </td></tr>
<tr><td>3 </td><td> d2 o1 </td></tr>
<tr><td>4 </td><td> d2 o2 </td></tr>
<tr><td>5 </td><td> d2 o3 </td></tr>
<tr><td>6 </td><td> d3 o1 </td></tr>
<tr><td>7 </td><td> d3 o2 </td></tr>
```

Just being able to access the parent loop is not good enough. For this, you have two options:

- Flatten the lists, as suggested by Rohan in the comments, or
- Create a new template tag that can act as a counter.

Flattening the list is the simplest option. In your view code, if you restructure your data like so:

```
flat_list = list({'d': d, 'o': o} for d in list1 for o in d['list2'])
```

You can then print the list like so:

```
{% for i in flat_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter}} </td>
        <td>{{ i.o.name}}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor  %}
```

However, this may not be possible, depending upon your data. If this is not possible, and the list can not be sensibly flattened, you will have to create a new counter template tag, which could act like so:

```
{% load counter_tags %}
{% counter_from 1 as counter %}
{% for d in list1 %}
    {% for o in d.list2 %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ counter }} </td>
            <td>{{ o.name}}</td>
          </tr>
    {% endfor  %}
{% endfor %}
```

Place the following in a `templatetags/counter_tags.py` file:

```
import itertools


class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, start, step=1):
        self.count = itertools.count(start, step)

    def next(self):
        return self.count.next()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.next())


@register.assignment_tag
def counter_from(start, step=1):
    return Counter(int(start), int(step))
```

And you have a loop-independent counter in your templates!